# PHP JSON is dropping first record

Tags: php, json, records

I have a line of code to convert data from database to JSON. The only problem is that the code I have seems to be dropping the first record. Any thoughts to why.

```
$return_arr = Array();

$query_qrySelect = "SELECT * FROM table";
$qrySelect = mysql_query($query_qrySelect, $database) or die(mysql_error());
$row_qrySelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($qrySelect);
$totalRows_qrySelect = mysql_num_rows($qrySelect);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qrySelect, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return_arr,$row);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$row_qrySelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($qrySelect);
```

is where you're "losing" your data.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `mysql_fetch_assoc` and never use the result anywhere (`$row_qrySelect` is never used).

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc):

> **Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.** mysql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.